# Can white light have two spectral peaks?

Tags: visible-light, perception, light-emitting-diodes

I was looking at a graph on the receptive ranges of the 3 types of color sensitive photoreceptors in us humans, and I had the idea that if we place only two peaks at the right places, we'll be able to activate all three receptors equally, and produce a perception of the combined light being white.

So, basically, a two-led white light source.

I did some googling and didn't find anything to this effect. Does anyone here know if this has been done, or if there's any reason why this couldn't be done?

Comment: Maybe, as this is more a physiological question, biology might be the better place to ask. But +1 from me

Comment: If the question is: "would a two-LED white light source work?", it's yes. But one-LED white light sources are even better.  =)  @SuperfastJellyfish's answer includes the spectrum of a one-LED white light system.  It's produced using one blue LED and yellow phosphors (which absorb some of the blue light and re-emit it as yellow light).  You didn't find a two-LED system when searching because there's no monetary reason to make it, when the one-LED system is cheaper and more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response (absorbance) of our optical sensory system is given by the following:
[image] <sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Photoreceptor cell - Humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoreceptor_cell#Humans))</sub>

The spectrum for mercury tube light is given by:
[image] <sub>(image from [Wikimedia - Fluorescent lighting spectra](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fluorescent_lighting_spectrum_peaks_labelled.gif) )</sub>

The spectrum for white LED is given by:
[image] <sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Light-emitting diode - Phosphor-based LED](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fluorescent_lighting_spectrum_peaks_labelled.gif))</sub>

What we finally see is a weighted spectra, weighed by the sensitivity of the eye for each colour as seen in the first graph. This is vastly different for the two white light sources. For example, in the tube light spectrum there is a contribution from the $0-400\,\mathrm{nm}$ range where as there is none in that of LED.

I think in order to make any progress on this we first need to know what all weighted spectra a white light can have. But then it becomes a question about perception. But once we have that, we can reverse engineer the all possible light spectrum that gives us white light and see if any one of them have two peaks.

Comment: Take away that blue peak from the LED spectrum, and what's left would look strongly yellow.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opponent_process for a brief explanation of why blue+yellow looks like white.

Comment: @SolomonSlow exactly! And the blue peak has to be stronger than the other because of the lower sensitivity of blue.